# Price Field Not Saving Programatically

Tags: 7, commerce

**Price** *Field Type* from the **Commerce** *module* package is not exportable for **Feeds**. So as a work-around, I saved my prices ('min price', 'hot price' and "deposit price') into  normal Float fields and just move the values to the **Price** *Field Types*  on-the-fly. And so here it is (set using *Rules*: After an item is saved of content type 'Property'):

```
$node->field_price_amount['und'][0]['value'] = [node:field-current-price-temp];
$node->field_hot_price_amount['und'][0]['value'] = [node-field-hot-price-temp];
```

etc.

and then applying the node_save($node) with $node->is_new set to FALSE.

All the other values are saving properly except for the field type defined by the **Commerce** module. No actual data saved to tables at all.

"$node->field_price" should be the right machine name I have defined for this field. But for some reason importing leads to error field_price_amount cannot be NULL. This is also weird. So I changed it to field_price_amount so it won't complain but still not saving despite no more errors in importing. (The db table is still named field_data_field_price but for some reason it is complaining as 'field_price_*amount* should not be null ).

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Seems like there is a column amount not value for a price field $node->field_price_amount['und'][0]['amount'] = [node:field-current-price-temp];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commerce price fields have a different data structure from standard fields.

i.e not:

```
$product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 500;
```

but instead

```
$product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] = 500;
$product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code'] = 'USD';
```

or just:

```
$product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array('amount' => 500, 'currency_code' => 'USD');
```

They also have a 'data' property for additional price component information.

More info: [`commerce_price_field_data_property_info`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21price%21commerce_price.module/function/commerce_price_field_data_property_info/DC)

Comment: Glad to hear it :)